# AngularJs project throws error angular not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, aws-cloud9

I am working on a simple application of AngularJs. I use cloud9 as an Ide and install Angular through bower in my project, but still get an error "angular not defined" in my .js file. 
Here is my code please help me.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <title>BlogIt!</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
  {{message}}
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.message = "Welcome to BlogIt!";
})
```

Comment: @31piy you've added ng-app with your edit, now the issue is no longer

Comment: @Sajeetharan -- I didn't. Please see the history. OP already had it but it was not visible since it wasn't formatted.

Answer (score 1):

You are not able to load angular.min.js on your page.

Try by changing like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
```

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.message = "Welcome to BlogIt!";
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <title>BlogIt!</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
  {{message}}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please don't poke the OP for answer's acceptance. If this is the correct answer, OP will eventually accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing ng-app

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
```

Comment: OP already has `ng-app` in the code. So this answer seems to be invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Add ng-app in your program.

It's the starting point of the application.

Comment: OP already has `ng-app` in the code. So this answer seems to be invalid.